# Clone DB table row through MVC in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005

Is there a simple solution for duplicating table rows in SQL Server as well as all table rows with foreign keys pointing to the cloned table row? I've got a "master" table and a bunch of "child" tables which have a foreign key into the ID of the master table. I need to not only create a perfect copy of the master table, but clone each and every child table referencing the master table. Is there a simpler way to do this than creating a new row in the master table, copying in the information from the row to be cloned, then going through each child table and doing the same with each row pointing to the cloned row in the master table?

I'm using a SQL Server 2005 Database accessed through C# ASP.net MVC 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

If by "simple" you mean is there is a procedure that can be called to do it, no there is not. However, you can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views such as `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` to query for the columns in a table or the list of related tables and dynamically build your INSERT statements to copy one row to another. Of course, this does not account for other uniqueness constraints that might be on the tables (e.g. a table with a Name column which requires that the values be unique).